# I need to create my own parser using yacc

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc, lex, flex-lexer

I need to create a parser for my own programming language using YACC.Can anyone help me with some suggestions or possibly a few tutorials ?

Comment: People are closing your question because "it appears to not be about programming".  YACC isn't programming?  I think that is a completely dishonest reason to close this question,  and if were OP, I'd be truly disappointed with SO.   I'm giving this question +1 as a protest, and if it is closed, I will vote to re-open.

Comment: @IraBaxter: The text is *"This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center"*.

Comment: The "help center" has some additional caveats but they aren't about programming, so the phrase "within the scope" is truly misleading.  You think that referring to footnotes makes it easier for newbies to understand what is happening to them?  All they see is "my question is getting closed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with the Bison reference manual itself. http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.pdf